# Translating Magento 2 Extension Using Theme Translation Files

Tags: magento2, i18n

I've installed [Magefan Blog](https://github.com/magefan/module-blog) using the composer. So I can't add a new translation to the extension itself.

I tried to add the translations to the theme i18n files on the path `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/i18n/ar_SA.csv`.

> "Blog","الأخبار",module,Magefan_Blog

But it doesn't work.

I've searched the web and find this tutorial:
[Translating Magento 2 Extension Using Theme Translation Files](http://wiki.plumrocket.com/Translating_Magento_2_Extension_Using_Theme_Translation_Files)

And I've added the following:

> "Magefan_Blog:Blog","الأخبار"

But it's not working too.

Comment: Where are you adding translation?

Comment: app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/i18n/ar_SA.csv, Updated to the question too. Thanks

Comment: create folder like this app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magefan_Blog/i18n/ar_SA.csv in your theme and try

Comment: Blog","الأخبار" you need to put text like this in  csv and make sure word should be same in file also

Comment: Thanks for your idea, I believe it will be helpful. Anyway, I was able to change this word from the extension configuration on its language storeview.

Comment: Okay Nd thank you